# Pull First Image from Tumblr Body in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, tumblr

I'm building a website with an external Tumblr blog and using JSON to pull information from the blog and place it on the website. I am running into an issue when attempting to put the image from the Tumblr {body} into my website as a separate entity from the actual text post for styling/CSS purposes. The  tag in HTML is present, but I cannot seem to pull it out of the larger

tag. Here is my code to pull the information from Tumblr:

```
<%= tumblr.each do |post| %>
                <div class="blog-item span4">
                  <span class="date"><%= post['date'] %></span>
                  <h3> <%= post['title'] %> </h3>
                  <div class="image">
                   <%= image_tag "http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8ci2mGzND1ruwmhv.jpg" %>
                  </div>
                  <p><%= post['body'].html_safe %></p>
                </div><!-- .blog-item span4 -->
<%end%>
```

Can anyone help me parse the image from a plain text post with a picture? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the conventions follow the [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api) Then I'd suggest it's `photo-url`

(Note: not tested)